# Python- Is it possible to open multiple Chrome web pages at once?

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working on a Python script to open multiple web pages at once, and then search.
Python will open them one by one but it's painfully slow. I have 12 tabs that open inside of Chrome.
Here's the code I'm using to open a website in a new tab for each website inside of Chrome. Any suggestions?   (Using PyCharm, Python 3.5)

```
driver.get('https://www.website1.com')


    driver.execute_script("window.open('');")  # opens new tab
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
    driver.get('website2.com')


    driver.execute_script("window.open('');")  # opens new tab
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[2])
    driver.get('website3.com')
```

Comment: you can make a test for each webpage with pytest and then use xdist plugin to run the tests in threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was opening one web page using-
driver.get('https://www.website1.com')

then emulating key strokes to open a new tab in chrome, type the web address and hit enter.
That seemed to be the fastest way to get the pages to load and not have to wait for them to load one and then move on to the next one.

Answer (score 5):

I'm new to this, but I hope this helps your problem. This will open a window and then open tabs within that window.

```
import webbrowser

url = 'http://website1.com'
url_1 = 'http://website2.com'

chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'

webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url_1)
```

How to have it open up a new browser since I can't get `open_new()` to work.

```
import webbrowser
import os

url = 'http://python.org/'

chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'

os.startfile('C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe', "open")

webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open_new(url)
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url + '/doc')
```

Comment: Great answer, short and sweet, tough to beat! Upvoting!

Comment: Ok so that loads the web pages faster, however, it opens the tabs in any chrome window that I have open. Is there a way to specify a new window and then tabs in that window?
I'll be sending search terms to the different handles once they open and I'm not sure how to specify the handle if it opens in an existing chrome window.

Comment: Depending on your settings in chrome, `webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open_new(url)` will open a new window. `.open_new_tab(url)` will open a new tab. That wouldn't work for me so I did this instead and it works but it adds a blank tab which I'm not sure how to avoid. I will add the code to my original answer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Now, one can simply do (with the default browser):

```
import webbrowser
url1 = "www.google.com"
url2 = "www.facebook.com"
webbrowser.open_new(url1)
webbrowser.open_new(url2)
```